# How to decode JSON string in PHP pass from android?

Tags: php, android, json

I want to decode json string in Php that is pass from android.

Suppose i have follwing json that comes from android
     {"name":"ajay"}
    and in php i do

```
<?php
$result=json_decode('$_POST',true);
$name=$result['name'];
$response=array();
$response["message"]=$name successfully parse in php;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This gives html tag in response.Is there is any way to solve this?

Comment: and? what is your question? you have to get the right $_POST field

Comment: Look at the following link, after a quick google: http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this link. Maybe this will be helpful:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Can you be a little descriptive.. Don't post only a  link as answer. You must explain the answer. or add a comment to the answer

Comment: Link-Only-Answers are not answers because the information might get lost if the link dies.

Answer (score 1):

This seems working fine for me

```
<?php
  $result=json_decode('{"name":"ajay"} ',true);
  $name=$result['name'];
  $response=array();
  $response["message"]="$name successfully parse in php";
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Check [php manual for json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.phphttp://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more

Comment: This gives html tag in response

Comment: You paste the code and run it. I dont get any html tag in the output for the above code. It will give you `{"message":"ajay successfully parse in php"}` as the output. May be you are modifying the output. If  so post the code you are trying

Comment: I am passing json string from android to Php.But i could not get JSON string in php.Could you please help me